# Is a 60 amp breaker adequate for a 240v sub-panel to my garage?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, garage, subpanel

150 panel in house. I want to run a 240 (sub-panel) feed to garage 25 feet away for 10,000 watt electric heater. There's room in the 150 panel. Would 60 amp breaker in the garage meet the 1.25 safety margin?

Comment: Is this an attached or a detached garage?

Comment: Is the sub panel just for the heater?  Or are you planning on running additional receptacles?

Answer (score 1):

You mention two different things:

- A specific appliance - 10,000 W electric heater
- A subpanel

Do you actually want/need a subpanel?

If you **only** need to connect the heater (i.e., you have plenty of power already available in the garage for lights, receptacles, etc.), just run a circuit (wire & breaker in main panel sized appropriately) and you're done. For a 240V heater, that would likely be just two hots + ground.

If you actually want to connect a **subpanel**, then:

- The wire & breaker in the main panel need to match - breaker protects wire, but should be sized for a **larger** load so that you can put other stuff in the subpanel
- The subpanel should (code experts can speak up as to whether this is "should" or "must" - I'm not sure) have a disconnect mechanism, which can be a main breaker ("main" of that panel, but in the subpanel, not the 150 main panel) **any size equal to or larger than the breaker in the main panel that feeds the subpanel**. So you might get a panel that includes a 125A main breaker and use that even though the feed might be 100A.
- To connect a subpanel you should use hot/hot/neutral/ground so that you can have 120V loads as well as 240V loads in the subpanel.
- The total of all the breakers in the subpanel can be more than the feed - e.g., you could have 60A 240V for the heater and 6 x 20A 120V for lights, receptacles, power tools, etc. for a total of 120A @ 240V but as long as you do not have everything running at full load all the time.

Answer (score 0):

yes the 60-amp would meet the minimum requirement. In addition, please keep in mind that you need at least #6 copper wire to feed the garage to handle the heat load. The house panel will need a 60-Amp breaker also.